# Expand image icon not showing with PrettyPhoto

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to help my father with his website, but I'm having a problem with PrettyPhoto.

The expand image function is present on the page (I can click on it as I know where it is), but the icon is not displayed at the top right of the image.

I have the function (allow_resize: true, /* Resize the photos bigger than viewport. true/false */) set to true.

See here: http://fleurusalgerie.fr/Planlivre.html#!prettyPhoto

All the other icons are correctly displayed.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions! :-(

Edit (you guys are so quick to respond, ty! Sorry for the missing info, this is my 1st post on here) :

Here is the related code:

```
<a href="Images/BookContents1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[design2]" 
title="Chapitres 1 à 8"><img class="border" src="Images/BookContents1.jpg" 
width="92" height="150" alt="Chapitres 1 à 8" /></a>

<a href="Images/BookContents2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[design2]" 
title="Chapitres 9 à 15"><img class="border" src="Images/BookContents2.jpg" 
width="92" height="150" alt="Chapitres 9 à 15" /></a>

<a href="Images/BookContents3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[design2]" title="Chapitres 16 à 20"><img class="border" src="Images/BookContents3.jpg" width="92" height="150" alt="Chapitres 16 à 20" /></a></p>
```

and here is a pic of the popup, with the expand image icon at the top right of it (which is displayed in preview as you can see in the image, but disappears once online, all the other icons shows normally online):
[expand image icon pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9YHX.jpg)

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question itself.

Comment: Which icon is missing?